# In jQuery, is this selector an older syntax and what does it do?

Tags: jquery

I see in the code there is

```
$(".add-to-list :select :selected")
```

using jQuery and we had jQuery 1.3.2, but upgraded to 1.4.2 recently.  The line above actually says syntax error...  was it for jQuery 1.3.2 but not 1.4.2, and what does it do -- any docs -- and how do you do that in 1.4.2?  thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That selector looks for all `option` elements that are `selected` within all `select` elements in all elements that have a class of `add-to-list`.

The reason it is throwing a syntax error is that `:select` is not a valid selector. It *was* valid in `1.3.2`, but has since been removed. Instead just use `select` to get HTML `select` elements.

The correct selector would be:

```
".add-to-list select :selected"
```

Comment: Seems like that!  check http://jsfiddle.net/EzepM/5/  using Firefox or Chrome...  if changed to jQuery 1.4.2 then won't work.  1.3.2 will give you results...

Comment: I think there used to be selectors for all input types (including :select)...  (meant to add this as a comment not an answer)

Comment: @Ryley +1, yep. They have since consolidated to just `:input` to get all `select`, `input`, and `textarea` elements.